# Data pipeline for big data transfer

Tags: database, rest, etl

Context:
Need to extract data from dB owned by another team to run some modeling. Frequency of extraction is biweekly. Data size is around 500k-1million rows.

Question:
I did direct connection by asking the other team to create a dB role for my extraction or get a dump file from them.

What are some of the ways that we can extract the data? Web services is good?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you have access to the source database, what is the specific problem that prevents you from importing the data?

Comment: the direct connection option is usually the best - provided that the roles access is defined properly. Yet, im asking if the direct access isnt available, what are some of alternative that is good for big volume data transfer